# Stuck in my procedure [ORACLE]

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure, oracle12c

I am trying to perform an operation on my procedure but it does not work for me. I want to show the name of a file next to the tables that it has but without repeating the name of the file, I explain better. Let's say I have this table:

```
    -----------------------------------
   |        file         |   name_table|
   | ----------------------------------|
   | /home/peter/f1.dbf  |   table1.1  |
   | /home/peter/f1.dbf  |   table1.2  |
   | /home/peter/f2.dbf  |   table2.1  |
   | /home/peter/f3.dbf  |   table3.1  |
   | /home/peter/f3.dbf  |   table3.2  |
    -----------------------------------
```

When I run my procedure it should show something like this:

```
File: f1.dbf
     Table1.1
     Table1.2
File: f2.dbf
     Table2.1
File: f3.dbf
     Table3.1
     Table3.2
```

I have tried the following procedure:

```
create or replace procedure files(p_user IN dba_segments.owner%type)
is
  cursor c_cursor is
  select d.file_name, s.segment_name, s.segment_type
  from dba_data_files d, dba_segments s
  where segment_type = 'TABLE'
  and s.owner=p_user;

  v_cursor c_cursor%rowtype;

begin
for v_cursor in c_cursor loop
  if v_cursor.segment_type='TABLE' then
    dbms_output.put_line('File' || v_cursor.file_name);
    dbms_output.put_line('  Table Nº:'' '|| v_cursor.segment_name);
  end if;
end loop;
end files;
/
```

But the result of my procedure is as follows:

```
File: /home/peter/f1.dbf
     Table1.1
File: /home/peter/f1.dbf
     Table1.2
File: /home/peter/f2.dbf
     Table2.1
File: /home/peter/f3.dbf
     Table3.1
File: /home/peter/f3.dbf
     Table3.2
```

I hope I explained well and thank you for the help.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you very much for the advice.

Comment: @Randomuser1204281 You need to order by file_name too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use two cursors instead of one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FILES (P_USER IN DBA_SEGMENTS.OWNER%TYPE)
IS
   CURSOR C_FILE
   IS
        SELECT D.FILE_NAME
          FROM DBA_DATA_FILES D, DBA_SEGMENTS S
         WHERE SEGMENT_TYPE = 'TABLE' AND S.OWNER = P_USER
      GROUP BY D.FILE_NAME;

   CURSOR C_SEGMENT (
      P_FILE   IN VARCHAR2)
   IS
      SELECT SEGMENT_NAME
        FROM DBA_DATA_FILES D, DBA_SEGMENTS S
       WHERE     SEGMENT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
             AND S.OWNER = P_USER
             AND D.FILE_NAME = P_FILE;
BEGIN
   FOR REC_FILE IN C_FILE
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('File' || REC_FILE.FILE_NAME);

      FOR REC_SEG IN C_SEGMENT (REC_FILE.FILE_NAME)
      LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('  Table Nº:'' ' || REC_SEG.SEGMENT_NAME);
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END FILES;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can Achieve your goal only with pure sql.

```
  select s_file, s_name
    from (  select d.file_name
                 , s.segment_name as s_name
                 , row_number() over(partition by file_name order by 1) rn
                 , case when grouping_id(segment_name) = 1 then 'File: ' || d.file_name end s_file
              from dba_data_files d, dba_segments s
             where segment_type = 'TABLE' and s.owner = user
          group by file_name, rollup(segment_name))
order by file_name, rn desc
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you type the file even if it is repeated. If you modified the code as described below, you will reach the solution easily:

1. Create a variable for file name and initialize it with empty `varchar` before the loop
2. Instead of typing the file name you should check whether the variable has the same value as the filename. If not, then type the file, otherwise do not type it
3. After you have handled the filename and typed if it was new, store the filename in the variable

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your report in SQLPlus, then you can simply use the BREAK command

```
break on file_name

select d.file_name, s.segment_name, s.segment_type
  from dba_data_files d, dba_segments s
  where segment_type = 'TABLE'
  and s.owner=&p_user
order by d.file_name
;
```